OS Maps API low quality via GeoServer WMS
When I publish OS Maps API following this instruction, the quality of the WMTS Tile Layer is excellent.
But if I use the published service as WMS in GeoServer, the quality drops very much for all formats (OpenLayers, PNG, PDF, etc.)

However, the quality is great when I add the same WMS from GeoServer to QGIS.

I need to use WMS for MapProxy configuration, but anyway I'm interested to know what the issue is.

I suspect that you are viewing the WMS between the scales provided by the OS, so GeoServer is up/down scaling and may be choosing the wrong interpolation method.  I can't remember if there are any options for that for you to try.
